# String to Object with reference

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a string to an object when there is a reference inside the string?

String:

> { "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq", "value" :
>   e.data.OrderNumber }

I already tried with JSON.parse and eval but I'm still getting an error on "e.data.OrderNumber"

Comment: `obj.value=e.data.OrderNumber `

Comment: That is not a valid JSON. `e.data.OrderNumber` should be treated as a string like this: `"e.data.OrderNumber"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `"value"` to empty string. Call `JSON.parse()` with `str` as parameter. Set `.value` of resulting object.

```
var str = `{"field":"OrderNumber","operator":"eq","value":""}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

obj.value = e.data.OrderNumber;
```

An alternative approach would be to utilize `JSON.parse()` [`reviver`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.parse) function, with `this` set to `e` using `Function.prototype.bind()`. If `key` is equal to `"value"` within the function create a variable `val` where the value is initially set to `undefined`. Use `.split()` to create an array of the property representations within the `key` `"value"`. `.slice()` the indexes following `0` from resulting array. Use `for..of` loop to get the value of `obj[arrayIndex]` through `obj[arrayIndex][propN]` where `propN` is the nth index of array; assign the value to the variable `val`. Return the variable `val` following loop, else return `value` parameter.

```js
var e = {
  data: {
    OrderNumber: 1
  }
};

var str = '{"field":"OrderNumber","operator":"eq","value":e.data.OrderNumber}';

str = str.replace(/((\w+.[\w.]+)(?=(\s+|)\}))/g, "\"$1\"");

var rev = function(key, value) {
  if (key === "value") {
    let [props, val] = [value.split(".").slice(1), void 0];
    for (let prop of props) {
      val = val === undefined ? this[prop] : val[prop];
    }
   return val;
  }
  return value;
};

var obj = JSON.parse(str, rev.bind(e));

console.log(obj);
```

You can also retrieve and set the value without having the property name using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/((\w+.[\w.]+)(?=(\s+|)\}))/g` to match word character followed by `.` followed by one of more word characters and `.` characters; `String.prototype.match()` to match word characters and create an array from the matches; `Array.prototype.reduce()` to iterate each depth of object properties for the `.length` of the array, return the last value at depth of array `.length` corresponding to object properties within original string.

```js
const e = {
  data: {
    OrderNumber: 1
  }
};

let str = '{ "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq", "value" : e.data.OrderNumber }';

str = str.replace(/((\w+.[\w.]+)(?=(\s+|)\}))/g, function(match) {
  let [,...props] = match.match(/[^.]+/g);
  return props.reduce(function(obj, prop) {
    return obj[prop]
  }, e); 
});

let obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj);
```

With resulting array from calls to `.match()`, `.shift()`, `.split()` on original string you can get the property values from `e` with destructuring assignment; use `.replace()` to set replacement string with corresponding value from `e`; then call `JSON.parse()` with resulting string as value to create a `javascript` object.

```js
const e = {
  data: {
    OrderNumber: 1
  }
};

let str = '{ "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq", "value" : e.data.OrderNumber }';

let re = /((\w+.[\w.]+)(?=(\s+|)\}))/g;

let obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(re
          , (() => ([,...props] = str.match(re).shift().split(".")
            , {[props[0]]:{[props[1]]:prop}} = e, prop)
            )()
          ));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If the string is known beforehand, an object initializer could be used instead of a string.

Comment: @Oriol  Yes, though actual text of Question is _"String to Object with refence"_

Answer (score 2):

Only real option you have to to use eval or new Function since what you have is not valid JSON due to the object property reference. There are security concerns with new Function and eval, so that is why this solution is not the best idea.

```
var str = '{ "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq", "value" : e.data.OrderNumber }';
var e = { data : { OrderNumber : 123456 } };
var x = new Function("return " + str)();
console.log(x.value);
```

BUT if I were you, I would see if there is a better way to do what you need instead of using a bandaid to fix the problem. What I would do is have an object and add the property or extend it.

```
var e = { data : { OrderNumber : 123456 } };
var obj = { "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq" };
obj.value = e.data.OrderNumber;
```

or

```
var e = { data : { OrderNumber : 123456 } };
var obj = { "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq" };
var result = {};
Object.assign(result, obj, {value : e.data.OrderNumber} );
```

Comment: Why `new Function` and not just `eval`?

Comment: @Evert personal preference?

Comment: but the data value not will be aways OrderNumber, i will use this string for a filter context: filter: JSON.parse(relationString)

Comment: The property does not matter. You can set it to whatever.

Comment: But to make the template works I would have to be with the direct string in the code, in my case it comes from the database

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/hd3v29ra/2/

You would simply need to adjust the order number to reside within quotations when you insert it into the string to be converted into an object:

example 1 using concatenated strings

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"field": "OrderNumber","operator": "eq","value":"' + e.data.orderNumber + '"}');
```

example 2 using ES6 Template Literals

```
var obj = JSON.parse(`{"field": "OrderNumber", "operator":"eq","value":"${e.data.orderNumber}"}`);
```

Comment: but the data value not will be aways OrderNumber, i will use this string for a filter context: filter: JSON.parse(relationString)

Answer (score 0):

There is the unsafe and evil `eval`:

```js
var e = {data: {OrderNumber: 123}};
var str = '{ "field": "OrderNumber", "operator": "eq", "value" : e.data.OrderNumber }';
console.log(eval('(' + str + ')'));
```

Do not use this with untrusted strings, it may run arbitrary code.

Comment: but the data value not will be aways OrderNumber, i will use this string for a filter context: filter: JSON.parse(relationString)

Answer (score 0):

It's worked with this:

```
    private static rev(key: any, value: any): any {
        if (key === "value") {
            let [props, val] = [value.split(".").slice(1), void 0];
            for (let prop of props) {
                val = val === undefined ? this[prop] : val[prop];
            }
            return val;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

And i use JSON.parse(relationString, this.rev.bind(e)) to call the method

Comment: The `javascript` at the current Answer is an exact duplicate of `javascript` at first stacksnippet at this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192130/