# Regular expression matching simple json within text

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm failing to write a reg exp that catches things all occurences of `{ key: something }` where `something` can be anything except `}` or . I've tried

```
{ key: [^}]* }
{ key: [^} ]* }
{ key: (.*?)({| ) }
{ key: (.*?)({) }
{ key: (?!.*({| )) }
{ key: (?!.*({)) }
```

of these the first one works *sometimes*, not according to any pattern I can see. I'm using these in javascript:

```
const pattern = '{ key: [^}]* }';
const regExp = new RegExp(pattern, 'igm');
let match = true;

do {
  match = regExp.exec(text);
  if (match) {
     // use result
  }
} while (match);
```

(I've also tried adding `regExp.lastIndex = 0;`, and setting `regExp = null` and redefining, in the loop).

However I don't think it's (only) a javascript problem; They don't work either on the [online regexp tester](https://regex101.com/).

I need the character indices; as an example I would like

```
kjh { key: sfdg } lkk { key: a }
```

to yield (5, 13) and (23, 10) (might be some off by one errors there)

Any suggestions?

EDIT: If relevant, the usecase is to highlight text following this pattern in an editor, using [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/575527).

Parse the JSON into an object with `JSON.parse`, find the key programmatically.

```
kjh { key: sfdg } lkk { key: a }
```

This is also not valid JSON. If this is some data from the server, serve it in some correct data transfer format (i.e. XML, YAML, *JSON*) and not some arbitrary, structureless string.

Comment: The usecase is to highlight text in an editor that follows this pattern (with entities from https://draftjs.org/), so it must be able to handle everything - will edit the OP. There still might be some approach similar to what you're saying though, I like it

Comment: @jorgen All the more reason to use a real parser than just plain regular expressions. Your code should be able to tell JSON apart from strings that _look_ like JSON.

Comment: Ok. So I'm thinking to find all occurences of `{` and `}`, try `JSON.parse` on what's between (including the brackets) and inspect the results. Sound?

Answer (score 0):

To match the value of `JSON` you can convert the object to valid `JSON` match the property surrounded by double quotes followed by `:` and any characters followed by closing `}`.

See also

- [How to filter Object using Array.prototype.filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232576/how-to-filter-object-using-array-prototype-filter)
- this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228715/) at [remove object from nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228492/remove-object-from-nested-array/36228715#36228715)
- [Text file to JSON, last few lines are not included in the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274723/text-file-to-json-last-few-lines-are-not-included-in-the-result/48276601#48276601)
- [String to Object with reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192023/string-to-object-with-reference/41192130#41192130)

```js
var o = {key:123};

var json = JSON.stringify(o);

var prop = `"key":`;

var re = new RegExp(`${prop}.+(?=})`);

console.log(json.match(re)[0].split(new RegExp(prop)).pop());
```